# Minimizing the maximum degree of a set of sets

Tags: co.combinatorics

Suppose that ${\cal C}$ is a set of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with the following properties:

1. $\{1,\ldots,n\}\notin {\cal C}$,
2. for all $x,y\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ there is $A\in {\cal C}$ such that $\{x,y\}\subseteq A$, and
3. $|A\cap B| \leq 1$ for all $A\neq B\in{\cal C}$.

For $j\in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ we set the *degree* of $j$ to be $\text{deg}(j) = |\{A\in {\cal C}: j\in A\}|$ and set $$m({\cal C}) = \max\big\{\text{deg}(j): j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\big\}.$$

Is it possible that $m({\cal C}) < n-1$? If yes, how small in terms of $n$ can $m({\cal C})$ become?

(You only need to answer the first question to get the answer accepted; the second question is a bonus question.)

Comment: Nice - can you put this as an answer? Or would it be better to delete the question entirely?

Comment: what if we take $\mathcal{C}$ to be the three sets $\{1,2\}$, $[n]\setminus \{1 \}$ and $[n]\setminus\{2\}$?

Comment: Very nice - all these examples escaped me! - I was wondering, what happens if you add a 3rd condition to the 2 stated in the question: $|A\cap B| \leq 1$ for all $A\neq B\in{\cal C}$. -- Just edited the question accordingly

Comment: In the third assumption,  any $\{x,y\}$ is included in one and only one set  (and maybe in $\mathcal{C}$ there are some more sets that are singletons). It follows $m\ge n-1$,doesn't it? (no it doesn't :) )

Comment: If I understand your argument correctly, we get that $|{\cal C}| \geq n-1$, but how does it imply that the maximum degree of all the points is $\geq n-1$? (Probably I'm missing something)

Comment: A simple example with $m = n/2 + 1$: For $n = 2k$ even, take as your ground-set $X$ the set of all points $(i,r)$ in the plane where $1 \leq i \leq k$ and $r \in \{ 0, 1 \}$. Take $\mathcal{C}$ as the set of all lines through at least two of these points.
(1) Not all lie on a line (if $k \geq 2$).
(2) Any two lie on a common line.
(3) Any two lines have at most one common point.
(4) Each point lies in $k+1$ lines.

Comment: Lovely example - if you post it as an answer, I'll vote it up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the 9-point affine plane $\ F_3\times F_3,\ $ over the 3-element Galois field $\ F_3.\ $ Then $\ n=9,\ $ while the respective $\ m(C)=4 < n-1$.

Here $\ C\ $ is the set of affine lines, i.e. sets described by the linear equations (homogeneous and non-homogenous, just like in an elementary school).

The explicit set of 4 straight lines which include point (0\ 0) is:

$$ \{(0\ 0)\ \ (0\ 1)\ \ (0\ 2)\}$$
$$ \{(0\ 0)\ \ (1\ 0)\ \ (2\ 0)\}$$
$$ \{(0\ 0)\ \ (1\ 1)\ \ (2\ 2)\}$$
$$ \{(0\ 0)\ \ (1\ 2)\ \ (2\ 1)\}$$

> 

Now let us consider a 6-point space which is a union of two parallel lines of the above plane, i.e. now $\ n=6.\ $ Then in family $\ C\ $ consists of the intersections of the straight lines with our 6-point space (all members of this new space are two 3-point sets, and nine 2-point sets). Now $\ m(C) = 4 < n-1. $ This time I believe that this $\ n=6\ $ is minimal.

Thge example is simple enough to forget about geometry--let our space be $\ \{\, 1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\,\}.\ $ Then let consist of two 3-point sets:

$ \{a+1\ \ a+2\ \ a+3\}\quad $ for $\ a=0\ $ and for $\ a=3$

and nine 2-point sets:

$$ \{a\ b\}\ :\ (a\ b)\in \{1\ 2\ 3\}\times\{4\ 5\ 6\}\ $$.

Comment: Can you describe this more concretely? I am afraid I don't understand your answer

Comment: I should get a minimal example as well (I just got distracted by editing above answer :) ).

Comment: Note that working in an arbitrary $F_p \times F_p$ for a prime number $p$ should yield a set $\mathcal{C}$ of lines with $m(\mathcal{C}) = p+1$, where the ground-set has size $n = p^2$. I don't know if the square root is optimal.

Answer (score 2):

I'll show that

> **THEOREM** $\ n=5\ $ is minimal.

First, observe that it's not possible for all members of $\ C\ $ to
have 2 (or less) points. **Indeed**, all sets $\ \{0\ x\},\ $ where $\ x\ne 0\, $ would belong to $\ C,\ $ hence $\  m(C)\ge n-1.\  $

Thus, we may assume that there is $\ A\in C\ $ such that $\ \{1\ 2\ 3\}\subseteq A.\ $ If there was only one point $\ b\notin A\ $ then
$\ \{a\ b\}\in C\  $ for every $\ a\in A,\ $ hence $\ m(C)\ge |A|=n-1\ $ -- a contradiction.

We see that the minimal $\ n\ $ is at least $\ 5.\ $

---

**Indeed**, we have a 5-point example consisting of complex numbers

$$ -1\qquad -\!i\qquad 0\qquad i\qquad 1 $$

The members of $\ C\ $ are defined as the nontrivial intersections of the Euclidean lines with the given 5-point set (where nontrivial means that the intersection has at least $\ 2\ $ different points). We see like Euclid would that $\ m(C)=3<4 = n-1.\ $ This proves the $\ n=5\ $ is correct and minimal. **END of PROOF**

> **REMARK**   Whenever we have a system described by Dominic (just don't insist on points being consecutive integers) then the trace of such a system on a subset forms a similar system.